# Convert matched column from long to wide

Tags: r, lookup

I have df.1

```
ID     B 
006007 M
123456 F
987654 F
```

And df.2

```
ID     B C
006007 M N
006007 M S
123456 F S
987654 F W
```

I'm trying to essentially look up **ID** to match from df.2 and return **C** into df.1, but creating a separate column for each possible answer if there are duplications in **df.2$ID** (i.e. convert **C** from long to wide). So I would end up with:

```
ID     B C1 C2 C3
006007 M N   S NA
123456 F NA  S NA
987654 F NA  NA W
```

Just to re-iterate I need one row for each ID, with each result for each ID in seperate columns.

Please let me know if you need more clarification and I really appreciate your help, guys.

Comment: You seem like you know the steps: use `merge` to combine the data frames, then use whatever your favorite long-to-wide conversion tool is to make it wide. Popular functions are `reshape2::dcast`, `data.table::dcast`, and `tidyr::spread`. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# merge the data
m = merge(df.1, df.2)

# convert it to wide
library(data.table)
dcast(m, ID + B ~ C, value.var = "C")
#       ID B    N    S    W
# 1   6007 M    N    S <NA>
# 2 123456 F <NA>    S <NA>
# 3 987654 F <NA> <NA>    W
```

I'll let you rename the columns to C1, C2, ..., if you really want to.

---

Using this data:

```
df.1 = read.table(text = "ID     B 
006007 M
123456 F
987654 F", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)

df.2 = read.table(text = "ID     B C
006007 M N
006007 M S
123456 F S
987654 F W", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)
```

Comment: Why to `merge` if `df.2` is super-set of `df.1`? Perhaps concept of `lookup` table is not clearly mentioned in OP.

Comment: I'm assuming that `df.2` being a super-set of `df.1` is due to this being a simple illustrative example. Maybe `df.2` has additional IDs that are conveniently omitted by the join. Maybe `df.1` has additional IDs that OP could include by setting `all.x = TRUE` in the `merge` call. I'm happy to take OP at their word that a lookup is needed.

Comment: I assumed slightly differently. i.e. `df.2` got only 2 columns as `ID` and `C`. Then `merge` would have copied value of `C` in `df.1` column.

Comment: Possibly, but in the example we have `df.2` has 3 columns.